# AJAX with jquery and XML

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm having a bit of trouble with my code below. I'm simply not getting any results at all.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "jqueryXML.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find("movie").each(function () {
                var title = $(this).find("title").text();
                $(".list ul").append("<li>" + title + "</li>");
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

XML:

```
<store>
 <movie>
  <title>movie1</title>
  <length>100</length>
 </movie>
 <movie>
  <title>movie2</title>
  <length>200</length>
 </movie>
</store>
```

It seems to be something wrong with the append line, but I'm not sure what.
Can anyone explain whats wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure if posted the entire xml but you would need the header tag : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: are you seeing the request for jqueryXML.xml in the network tab of developer tools? are you getting a response or is there an error code?

Comment: Yeah, the header tag is in there aswell. I can do something like alert(title) instead, and that will show one alert box with movie1 and then another with movie2. So the call seems functional, however the append that I'm trying to do leads to nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code itself looks fine; you might check:

- xml is being returned by the ajax call, and
- you have class "list" before <ul> in your HTML: e.g.

<div class="list"><ul>

not

<ul class="list">

Comment: Yeah you're right. It's working now. I actually had another ul element in my css with an overflow hidden * facepalm *, which i didn't notice.. ah well. I'll mark this as the solution.